# create custom section background

Tags: html, css, sections

I have tried to achieve something like in the picture below.

I have used polygon but unfortunately this is not supported by IE. Also i don't want to use SVG.

Is there any other solution to achieve that?
the solution should also be responsive if possible.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use SVG?

Comment: As i work with DIVI, and i am not able to add it customer frindly, so that he can also change some stuff, without to do anything in code

Answer (score 0):

I found this sample in jsfiddle for IE using clipPath, it may help:

```
<clipPath id="clip-triangle">
                <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 112 13, 240 13, 240 250, -250 250" />
            </clipPath>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2wu0dwrL/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is in a svg. So it can not use it on my example.